# Jquery toggle buttons deselect using .siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, toggle

I am trying to make an interface element where there are three buttons.

Only one or none buttons can be selected. I.e. the buttons are faded out to start with, when the user clicks one it lights up, the other two remain faded.

If the user then clicks another button, any other buttons get faded out and the one the user clicked on highlights. This is not a problem.

The problem comes when I am trying to get a currently highlighted button to go back to a faded state if the user clicks on it, so you are left with no highlighted buttons.

This is where I have got to:

```
$('.gradeButtons button').click(function() {
        if (!$(this).siblings().hasClass('quoteGrading'))
        {
            $('.gradeButtons button').addClass('quoteGrading')
        }
        if (!$(this).hasClass('quoteGrading'))
        {
            $(this).addClass('quoteGrading')
        } else {

            $(this).removeClass('quoteGrading')
        }

    })
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="control-group gradeButtons">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger quoteGrading">H</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning quoteGrading">W</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info quoteGrading">C</button>
            </div>
```

'quoteGrading' provides the faded out/inactive effect.

How can I make it work properly where only one or none buttons can be highlighted (not have 'quoteGrading' class applied)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kX2vC/)

```
$(function() {
  $('.gradeButtons button').on("click",function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('quoteGrading');
    $(this).toggleClass('quoteGrading');
    $("input.inp").hide();
    $("#"+this.id+"input").toggle($(this).hasClass("quoteGrading"));  
  });
});
```

using

```
<div class="control-group gradeButtons">
  <button type="button" id="H" class="btn btn-danger">H</button>
  <button type="button" id="W" class="btn btn-warning">W</button>
    <button type="button" id="C" class="btn btn-info">C</button><br />
  <input type="text" class="inp" placeholder="H - message" id="Hinput" /><br/>  
  <input type="text" class="inp" placeholder="W - message" id="Winput" /><br/>  
  <input type="text" class="inp" placeholder="C - message" id="Cinput" /><br/>  
</div>
```

and

```
.quoteGrading { color:red }
.inp { display:none }
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I click a button for the first time they all have the class stripped. Subsequent clicks leave all but the clicked button without the class.

Comment: just change .removeClass() to adClass()

Comment: @Mark Walters +1 Thanks! That works, will except mps answer as it got me 80% of the way there.

Comment: No worries, I think some people would add an active class and have the default style as the faded one in which case .removeClass would have been right

Comment: Is there a simple way I can bring in a hidden input field which value is set according to which button is used? "data-" attribute or a bunch of "ifs" do you think is best?

Comment: Use .index() have a look at the jQuery docs on the use of it. It will give the index 0-2 in your case of the selected element. Try using alert() and $(this).index() in your code to see what the result is and use this.

Comment: My code works as well as it can with the information provided. See the demo. If adding a class has some fading effect, then the fading effect you are talking about is not part of the code you gave.